# Can not start aerospike on centos 6.3, no version information available (required by bin/asd)

Tags: aerospike, libcrypto

Has any body encounter this problem?

OS Version: CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

Aerospike version： Community Edition 3.12.1

Error Message:

```
# bin/aerospike start
error: start failed due to an error.
/home/work/aerospike-server/bin/asd: /lib64/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /home/work/aerospike-server/bin/asd)
/home/work/aerospike-server/bin/asd: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /home/work/aerospike-server/bin/asd)
Apr 07 2017 04:03:02 GMT: WARNING (cf:misc): (hardware.c:626) no NUMA information found in /sys
```

Comment: Could you share the h/w you are running on?

Comment: we finally compile from the source code..

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you may be missing the zlib library.

I was able to install zlib on centos 6.3 minimal, along with the rpm version of aerospike 3.12.1 CE server for Centos/el6

Issue seems to with the .tgz version. RPM version works fine:

```
sudo yum install zlib-devel -y
wget http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/3.12.1/artifact/el6
tar xvf el6 
cd aerospike-server-community-3.12.1-el6/
sudo ./asinstall
```

I didn't get the  /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 warning with the Centos RPM install (./asinstall) .

Aerospike binary rpms can be found here for Centos/Redhat:

http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/3.12.1/

Outputs:

```
rpm -Uvh aerospike-tools-3.12.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.0)(64bit) is needed by aerospike-tools-3.12.1-1.el6.x86_64
Installing server
rpm -Uvh aerospike-server-community-3.12.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.0)(64bit) is needed by aerospike-server-community-3.12.1-1.el6.x86_64
```

yum install zlib-devel

and aerospike server.

```
root@centos6 aerospike-server-community-3.12.1-el6]# ./asinstall 
Installing tools dependencies
Installing tools
rpm -Uvh aerospike-tools-3.12.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
Installing /opt/aerospike
Adding group aerospike
Adding user aerospike
   1:aerospike-tools        ########################################### [100%]
Writing /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/aerospike.pth
Adding python path /opt/aerospike/lib/python
Installing server
rpm -Uvh aerospike-server-community-3.12.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:aerospike-server-commun########################################### [100%]
[root@centos6 aerospike-server-community-3.12.1-el6]# asd --version
Aerospike Community Edition build 3.12.1
[root@centos6 aerospike-server-community-3.12.1-el6]# /etc/init.d/aerospike start
Increasing read socket buffer limit (/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max): 131071 -> 15728640
Increasing write socket buffer limit (/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max): 131071 -> 5242880
Starting and checking aerospike: Apr 10 2017 19:41:19 GMT: WARNING (cf:misc): (hardware.c:626) no NUMA information found in /sys
                                                           [  OK  ]
[root@centos6 aerospike-server-community-3.12.1-el6]# /etc/init.d/aerospike status
asd (pid 2080) is running...
```

Version of openssl:

```
[root@centos6 aerospike-server-community-3.12.1-el6]# rpm -qa|grep openssl
openssl-1.0.1e-57.el6.x86_64
```

Libcrypto:

```
[root@centos6 aerospike-server-community-3.12.1-el6]# rpm -ql openssl|grep crypto
/usr/lib64/.libcrypto.so.1.0.1e.hmac
/usr/lib64/.libcrypto.so.10.hmac
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10
```

The non-RPM (.tgz) version you used seemed to have been compiled in Debian7 and using an older libcrypto.

```
# hexdump -C -n 128 -s 0x258750 /root/aerospike-server/bin/asd
00258750  63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |c...............|
00258760  33 2e 31 32 2e 31 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |3.12.1..........|
00258770  54 75 65 20 41 70 72 20  20 34 20 32 30 3a 32 34  |Tue Apr  4 20:24|
00258780  3a 30 31 20 55 54 43 20  32 30 31 37 00 00 00 00  |:01 UTC 2017....|
00258790  41 65 72 6f 73 70 69 6b  65 20 43 6f 6d 6d 75 6e  |Aerospike Commun|
002587a0  69 74 79 20 45 64 69 74  69 6f 6e 00 64 65 62 69  |ity Edition.debi|
002587b0  61 6e 37 00 00 61 6c 6c  6f 63 2e 63 00 28 75 6e  |an7..alloc.c.(un|
002587c0  75 73 65 64 29 00 64 69  73 00 6d 65 6d 6f 72 79  |used).dis.memory|
002587d0
```